# privacy error when I click on meta link from help dropdown menu.

Tags: discussion, support

[image: img]

For other site meta (for example, AU) https is present.

I am using google chrome. I got the *privacy error* when I click on [meta link](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/) from *help* dropdown menu. But it is not showing any error when I click on  my profile [meta user](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2708/ravan).

Comment: I'm not sure why specifically the meta doesn't work, although it seems to be some configuration required with CloudFlare, but the https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/ does.

Comment: @LewisGoddard yes :)

Comment: Are you using Vivaldi?

Comment: @RolandiXor nope, I am using google chrome.

Comment: I have edited my post, any one got same error from the link?

Comment: Is your time and day correct? I got this after resetting my BIOS settings which had put the time to  1,1,2015 (this happened last year)

Answer (score 3):

The HTTPS support for the sites in the Stack Exchange network [is not fully enabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites), so you shouldn't worry much about this. When it will be announced that finally SE is https'ed, you can report it as actual bug.

Comment: my apologize @nicael

Comment: @Ravan Thanks for understanding :)